# Loading opencv-js asynchronously in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, opencv

How to load the opencv-js ([https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/d84/tutorial_js_usage.html#:~:text=You%20may%20want%20to%20load%20opencv.js%20asynchronously%20by%20async%20attribute%20in%20%3Cscript%3E%20tag.%20To%20be%20notified%20when%20opencv.js%20is%20ready%2C%20you%20can%20register%20a%20callback%20to%20onload%20attribute.](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/d84/tutorial_js_usage.html#:%7E:text=You%20may%20want%20to%20load%20opencv.js%20asynchronously%20by%20async%20attribute%20in%20%3Cscript%3E%20tag.%20To%20be%20notified%20when%20opencv.js%20is%20ready%2C%20you%20can%20register%20a%20callback%20to%20onload%20attribute.)) asynchronously in React JS component?

if I import, it's taking forever to load.

I tried this but it keeps failing:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, Component } from "react";

// REFERENCES: https://elfi-y.medium.com/how-to-create-async-scripts-in-react-816ca464704c
// 2. https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/d84/tutorial_js_usage.html

interface IThirdPartyProps {
  id: String;
}
const openCVScript = () => {
  const script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src =
    "D:\\Projects\\15_HGA_Smart_Maintenance\\smart-maintenance\\Frontend\\src\\assets\\js\\version_3\\opencv.js";
  script.id = "opencvjs";
  script.onload = "video()";
};
const Video: React.FC<IThirdPartyProps> = (props) => {
  if (typeof window == "undefined") {
    return null;
  }
  if (document.getElementById("opencvjs") === null) {
    openCVScript();
  }
  let arucoDictionary = new cv.Dictionary(cv.DICT_6X6_100);
  console.log(arucoDictionary);
  return (
    <div data-id={props.thirdPartyId} data-type="interactive">
      <video
        class="hideVideo"
        id="input_video"
        width="640"
        height="480"
      ></video>
      <canvas
        class="outputVideo"
        id="output_video"
        width="640"
        height="480"
      ></canvas>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Video;
```